# How to iterate through the files in a folder - Part II?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote this code to iterate from the files of a folder:

```
function showList() {    
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById('0B9HEC6UUJ_rsYWNPYko0MsrBRU0');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  Logger.log("files = " + files);
  arrayList = [];
  for (var file in files) {        
    Logger.log("file = " + file);
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    var newArray = [fileName, "some info", fileId];
    arrayList.push(newArray);
  }
```

But in this line `var fileName = file.getName();`, I got this error: `TypeError: Cannot find function getName in object 0`. 
The logs show this:

[image]

It seems there are files, but not the file that should get in the for loop. How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many problems in your js code:
1) thats not how you use 'in' in js. File will be an index so you need to do files[file]
2) even then its still wrong because iterating an array with 'in' will give you other things like the 'length' property.
Look up in the web how to iterate a js array.

Comment: Hi, @Zig Mandel, I change the code using files[file] and it worked. Thanks!